# How to create txt files named as file listed by the command 'dir'?

Tags: list, batch-file, rename, createfile

I need to create a txt file with the same name (excluded the extension) for each file present into a directory. For instance in a directory I have a file named `setup.exe`, I'd like to add an empty txt file into the same directory named `setup.txt`.

Is this able and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from `cmd`

```
FOR /R "C:\your_folder" %f IN (*.*) DO (TYPE NUL > %~pf%~nf.txt)
```

If you're inside the working directory, you can skip the path

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.*) DO (TYPE NUL > %~pf%~nf.txt)
```

If you're planning to run from `bat` file, use two %%

```
FOR /R "C:\your_folder" %%f IN (*.*) DO (TYPE NUL > %%~pf%%~nf.txt)
```

To exclude existing `txt` files,

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.*) DO (IF %~xf NEQ .txt (TYPE NUL > %~pf%~nf.txt))
```

Comment: Great! You have undertood exacly what I need. Thank You.

Comment: You can add a variant "working directory" like ---------------  for /R . %f in (*.*) do (type nul > %~pf%~nf.txt)

Comment: As an additional note, if you use a wildcard for your input files, you should, use a method of excluding `.txt` files. This would prevent you from effectively emptying all existing text files with content from every directory within that tree.

Comment: Does exist a way to exlude .txt files already present not declaring in input but sent to >nul output the files that has .txt extesion? In bash with a bit trouble I'd can do it but in dos I've not idea how to set a filter to output that hijack for a specific file extension. This is quite important because if into a already present .txt file there are important files not backuped and if i loose maybe the list of all my contacts for instance or info that I can't retrive in no mannerr this would be a disaster. Thanks for help me

Comment: @AndrewNexintong i'd updated the answer to exclude any existing `txt` files

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine. I just discovered that in presece of 2 o more identical file name but with diferet extensions the script make only 1 .txt file, this is a bad news. Do you think is possible to create .txt file that include the full file name included extension and adding to it the extesion .txt?  For instance "setup.exe" becomes "setup.exe.txt. Thanks to all for the help you are given to me

Comment: I tested and and now existing txt remain untouched. Good. But still the problem when two files have the same filename but different extensions. In case of 2 o more file with the same name and different extension it makes only one .txt file. So, if I have in one directory  setup.exe setup.ini setup.dll setup.txt i get only one file .txt named    setup.txt. Does is possible to print the full file name for each file? for instance  setup.exe.txt or setup.dll.txt. Thanks for help me

Comment: If you want to get the full file name, you can use `%f` directly. Like `FOR /R %f IN (*.*) DO (IF %~xf NEQ .txt (TYPE NUL > %f.txt))`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. My congratulations, you are very expert and able to understand the needs of the user. Have a nice weekend